# Compression Algorithm of 4 characters

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a Map of 4 values.
Let us take keys 0-3 for them and imagine that only these 4 keys are used(eg. 0120123102312313..)
Is there an effecient way to compress this string lossless?

Comment: You have 5 possible values: 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: Edit: I know. typo

Comment: In that case I fixed your other instance of a 4 for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no information about the distribution of elements (we don't know that any element is more common than others), we can use the following technique.

The minimum amount of information needed to store one of 4 values is just 2 bits: 00, 01, 10, or 11 can represent the 4 distinct elements in the map. Then, if you have `n` characters in your string, you can transform that into a bitstring of length `2n`, e.g., the string `12313` becomes a bitstring `01 10 11 01 11` (with spaces added for clarity).

If you use a base 36 encoding of the string (using the 10 digits plus 26 characters), you can turn 5 bits at a time into a single character (since 2^5 = 32 <= 36). This results in a string of `2/5 * n` characters, or a `2.5x` compression compared to your original string.

You can squeeze more out of the technique by using a different encoding with more distinct characters. For example, 10 digits + 26 uppercase letters + 26 lowercase letters + 2 punctuation chars = 64 characters, so you can turn 6 bits into one printable ASCII character using that kind of encoding.

---

If the distribution of elements is very skewed (for instance, 0 is very common, while 1, 2, and 3 are very rare), then you can take a look at [Huffman encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). However I suggest first using the approach I described above, since it is much simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: I also thought about the 2 bit representation but didnt know base 36 encoding. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can squeeze more out of the technique by using a different encoding with more distinct characters. For example, 10 digits + 26 uppercase letters + 26 lowercase letters + 2 punctuation chars = 64 characters, so you can turn 6 bits into one printable ASCII character.

Comment: Why restrict it to printable ASCII characters?

Comment: @ruakh If there's a restriction that the encoding be a String (as opposed to a bitstring, or an array of 8-bit chars), then usually it's better to not have unprintable characters so that you can tell what's going on...

Comment: @pkpnd: I see no evidence of such a restriction in the question. (And note that this question is not tagged with any particular language; there exist languages where arrays of eight-bit "characters" *are* "strings".)

Comment: @ruakh Sure. But that kind of extension should be pretty obvious to anyone who is ok with unprintable characters, since I give multiple examples of different ways of turning bits into characters.

Comment: @pkpnd: I think you may be overestimating the OP's level of experience. (S)he probably doesn't even *know* whether (s)he's "ok with unprintable characters".

Comment: @ruakh Then I would highly recommend to _inexperienced_ users to stick to printable characters. Basically, my answer is, "If you're lost and just want a simple answer, here is a simple and safe way of accomplishing your goals. But if you're advanced enough to _really_ understand what's going on, then I've provided all the reasoning necessary for you to generalize the approach to suit your needs."

Comment: @pkpnd: I see. In that case I think we'll have to agree to disagree.